# AutoMapper figure out inheritance when mapping from C# Dynamic/ExpandoObject

Tags: c#, dynamic, automapper, expandoobject

I have an issue where i'm trying to use AutoMapper to map a Dynamic object that's coming from a database (MongoDB for clarity, but I figure that's irrelevant) in to a specific class.

The class inheritance information is stored in an attribute _t (done at serialisation by Mongo) - how do I instruct AutoMapper to use the class information in _t when creating the underlying object that includes inheritance?

Here's my class information

```
class Person
{
public string id { get; set; }
public Foo Foo { get; set; }
}
class Foo
{
public string name { get; set; }
public string _t { get; set; }
}
class Bar : Foo
{
public string size { get; set; }
}
```

My incoming dynamic object looks like this:

```
Person.id = "Bob"
Person.Foo.name = "Bob"
Person.Foo._t = "Bar"
Person.Foo.size = "123"
```

When I use automapper to map it to Person using this code

```
        var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {});
        var mapper = configuration.CreateMapper();
        Person Person = mapper.Map<Person>(MyDynamic);
```

The resulting Person.Foo is not of type Bar. Which I fully undertstand (why) that would be the case, as AutoMapper has no understanding of what the original class was. But considering the information on class is stored in _t, can I instruct AutoMapper to use that to ensure that Person.Foo is of type Bar?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it the following way:

```
dynamic person = new ExpandoObject();

person.Foo = new ExpandoObject();
person.Foo.name = "Bob";
person.Foo._t = "Bar";
person.Foo.size = "123";

var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<dynamic, Person>().ConvertUsing((src, dst, ctx) =>
    {
        if (src.Foo._t == "Foo")
        {
            return new Person
            {
                Foo = ctx.Mapper.Map<Foo>(src.Foo)
            };
        }
        else
        {
            return new Person
            {
                Foo = ctx.Mapper.Map<Bar>(src.Foo)
            };
        }
    });
});

var mapper = configuration.CreateMapper();
Person p = mapper.Map<Person>(person);
```

Note: the above example doesn't handle the case if `Foo` is `null`, but should work for the exact problem you outlined in your question.

Comment: this is going to get me on the right path (I think), but the issue is that the Person class actually has another property in it (i've edited my original post to show that), so I can't do a return new Person, i need to map the properties within Person too.

Comment: I've tried to map the inherited class instead, but I get a stackoverflow when trying to do this:

                cfg.CreateMap<dynamic, Foo>().ConvertUsing((src, dst, ctx) =>
                {
                    if (src._t == "Bar")
                    {
                        return ctx.Mapper.Map<Bar>(src);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return null;
                    }
                });

Comment: do you know if it's possible for auto-mapper to map the children in the object before it maps the parent?

I've tried mapping the child type with a CreateMap against Foo, but in that instance, Foo never contains the properties of Bar. Trying to find ways of mapping Bar properly, whilst also maintaining the properties of the parent Person object.